# Nhibernate and db notifications

Tags: nhibernate, events

is there any notification support that nhibernate has in its framework that cna be used to register db changes?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the source of the changes you want to listen to. NHibernate can listen to changes from it's own ISessionFactory, but not from any process changing the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean something like the SqlDependancy and SqlNotification objects, then no it doesn't.  These are driven by SQL Notification Services in MSSQL 2005 / 2008, whereas NHib works with a number of databases.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 1):

You can configure log4net to log all queries into the file. How to do it you can find [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx)
Or if you need to perform some custom action before query you can use [listeners](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx)